# Are there any pre-trained non english model of deepspeech?

Tags: deep-learning, speech-to-text

I want to try `deepspeech` model.

I founded only english pre-trained model

Are there any other pre-trained not english model of `deepspeech` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Coqui](https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT), a fork of Mozilla DeepSpeech created by former Mozilla DeepSpeech developers. It is well maintained and [there are models for a lot of languages](https://coqui.ai/models).